# why is `find -xdev` showing dirs on all partitions?

Tags: filesystems, find, partition

While researching another problem, I noticed (annotations added)

```
me@it: ~ $ date ; sudo find / -maxdepth 1 -xdev -type d | grep -ve '/$' | sort
Thu Aug 31 14:58:25 MST 2017
/bin
/boot         [*]
/.config
/dev
/etc
/home         [*]
/lib
/lib64
/lost+found
/media
/mnt
/opt
/proc
/root
/run
/sbin
/srv
/sys
/tmp
/usr
/var
```

However I also know

```
me@it: ~ $ date ; lsblk
Thu Aug 31 14:52:58 MST 2017
NAME                  MAJ:MIN RM   SIZE RO TYPE  MOUNTPOINT
sda                     8:0    0 465.8G  0 disk
├─sda1                  8:1    0  16.6G  0 part
├─sda2                  8:2    0  97.7G  0 part
├─sda3                  8:3    0   500M  0 part  /boot  [*]
├─sda4                  8:4    0     1K  0 part
└─sda5                  8:5    0   351G  0 part
  └─LVM2_crypt        254:0    0   351G  0 crypt
    ├─LVM2_crypt-swap 254:1    0   3.9G  0 lvm   [SWAP]
    ├─LVM2_crypt-root 254:2    0    20G  0 lvm   /
    └─LVM2_crypt-home 254:3    0 327.1G  0 lvm   /home  [*]
sr0                    11:0    1  1024M  0 rom
```

So why is `find / -xdev` showing `/boot` and `/home`? FWIW, the order of `-maxdepth 1` and `-xdev` does not seem to be causing the problem:

```
me@it: ~ $ sudo su -
it ~ # date ; diff -wB <(find / -maxdepth 1 -xdev -type d | sort) <(find / -xdev -maxdepth 1 -type d | sort)
Thu Aug 31 15:09:53 MST 2017
it ~ # logout
```

Am I missing something? If not, why am I seeing `/boot` and `/home` in the 1st spew above?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`find -xdev` *doesn't descend* into directories that are mount points, but it still lists them. Try `find / -xdev -maxdepth 2`, you'll see that `/dev`, `/proc`, `/sys` and any other mount point are listed but their contents are not.

I think the rationale is that the mount point is present on the parent filesystem — even though what `find` lists is the root of the mounted filesystem and not the directory that serves as a mount point.

There's no convenient way to omit mount points. If you do post-processing, you can check that they're on the same device as the root of the traversal by comparing the output of `df -P` or `stat -c %d` (on Linux). But that's quite a lot of overhead for a rare situation.

Comment: In summary: `stat -c "%d %n" $(find / -mindepth 1 -maxdepth 1 -type d) | grep "^$(stat -c %d /)" | sed -e 's/[^ ]* //' | sort`

Answer (score 0):

There is a `boot` directory in the root file system.

```
find [...] -maxdepth 2
```

should not show the contents of `/boot`, though.